# Equality between limit of complex sequence $n\log(z_n)$ and $n(z_n-1)$

Tags: probability-theory, limits, complex-numbers

I am trying to understand the proof of theorem 16.6 of Probability Theory by A. Klenke (3rd version).

I have a problem:

- how can I show that these limits are the same if one of them exists? $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(z_n-1) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\log(z_n)$ where $z_n$ is a complex sequence.

I know that, based on Taylor expansion of the logarithm, $|\log(z_n)-(z_n-1)|\leq|z_n-1|^2$ if $|z_n-1|\leq 1/2$ with $z_n$ again a complex number.

Any hints or solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n(z_n-1)$ exists and is equal to $c$ with $\lvert c \rvert \gt 0$. Then eventually $n\lvert z_n -1 \rvert\le  2 \lvert c \rvert$. Therefore for $n$ large enough, you have using the inequality you provided

$$\lvert n\log(z_n)-n (z_n-1)\rvert \leq n\lvert z_n-1 \rvert^2 \le 4\frac{\lvert c \rvert^2}{n}$$ which leads to the desired conclusion that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n \log z_n = c$.

You can proceed in a similar way for the second equality.

Comment: Easy…after seeing the solution. Many thanks. Before accepting the response, are you familiar with the theorem I am referring in the OP? If so, I would like to add some more questions on that proof, if the guidelines allow this.

Comment: Or less precisely (but sufficiently): $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h=1$ (equivalently, $\lim_{z\to1}\frac{\log z}{z-1}=1$).

Comment: @Enrico To get the bounding you quoted in the question, you can use Taylor expansion of the logarithm $\log (z_n) =\log (1+(z_n-1))$, substract $z_n-1$ and bound the reminder using $\lvert z_n-1\rvert \lt 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also provide me some hints to show the second equality when the limit that exists is the one involving the $\log$? I am not able in reversing the inequality I provided. Thanks.

Comment: @Enrico As $n \log z_n$ converges, $\log z_n$ converges toward zero. And therefore $z_n$ towards one. Based on that you can leverage again the given inequality.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Is it correct? $|n\log(z_n)-n(z_n-1)|=n|\log(z_n)-(z_n-1)|\leq n|z_n-1|^2$, that means that $|\log(z_n)-(z_n-1)|\leq |z_n-1|^2$. Since $(z_n-1)$ tends to zero, eventually $|z_n-1|\leq\epsilon$ and so the limits are the same. I am not used to complex limit and logarithm: $(z_n-1)$ tends to real number 0 or has modulus zero? Thanks for the patience.

Comment: @Enrico In complex analysis, saying that the sequence of complex $\{z_n\}$ converges to $c$ means that the (real) sequence of modulus $\{\lvert z_n - c \rvert \}$ converges to zero.